# Why MongoDB's db.getRoles is returning empty?

Tags: mongodb, security

I installed the latest mongod - [From this link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)

Then I was trying to create user and I get error readWriteAnyDatabase role not found. Hence I do a little more debugging

```
> db.getRoles()
[ ]
> use admin
switched to db admin
> db.getRoles()
[ ]
```

and now I don't see any default list of Roles? any clue.

I am on version 4.4.4

Comment: Hi, are you looking for the list of [Built-in Roles](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#built-in-roles)?

Comment: Your question is related to [MongoDB Security](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/security/index.html). Lookup topics of Authentication and Authorization to start with.

Comment: yes I am looking in built in roles